# When referencing favicons, is MIME-type declaration (using the type attribute) obligatory?

Tags: html, svg, png, favicon

When referencing a `<link rel="icon">` in the `<head>` of an HTML document, is it obligatory to declare the **MIME Type** of the icon image using the attribute `type="[MIME TYPE HERE]"`?

Or is the `type` attribute optional?

**E.g.**

Is it compulsory to write:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/my/favicon.png" sizes="57x57" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/my/favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
```

Or is still valid to write:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/my/favicon.png" sizes="57x57">
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/my/favicon.svg">
```

---

**My reason for asking this question:**

Today, on the subject of favicons, I read:

> The main favicon can be an SVG of any size. The type
> `type="image/svg+xml"` is unnecessary.
>
> **Source:** https://medium.com/swlh/are-you-using-svg-favicons-yet-a-guide-for-modern-browsers-836a6aace3df

I don't feel entirely uncomfortable omitting the `type` but if I can confirm from an official source that it's definitely **not necessary** then I'm willing to try getting used to not including it in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** My tentative conclusion is that the `type` attribute is not obligatory in `<link rel="icon" />` *but it's nevertheless a good idea to include it*.

---

**Mozilla Developer Network** (**MDN**) states:

> If there are multiple `<link rel="icon">`s, the browser uses their
> `media`, `type`, and `sizes` attributes to select the most appropriate
> icon.
>
> **Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

The **Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group** (**WHAT-WG**) states:

> If multiple icons are provided, the user agent must select the most
> appropriate icon according to the `type`, `media`, and `sizes`
> attributes [...] There is no default type for resources given by the
> icon keyword. However, for the purposes of determining the type of the
> resource, user agents must expect the resource to be an image.
>
> **Source:** https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#rel-icon

The **WHAT-WG** also states:

> If the `type` attribute is present, then the user agent must assume
> that the resource is of the given type [...] If the attribute is
> omitted, but the external resource link type has a default type
> defined, then the user agent must assume that the resource is of that
> type [...] If the attribute is omitted, and the external resource link
> type does not have a default type defined, but the user agent would
> fetch and process the linked resource if the type was known and
> supported, then the user agent should fetch and process the linked
> resource under the assumption that it will be supported.
>
> User agents must not consider the `type` attribute authoritative —
> upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use the `type`
> attribute to determine its actual type. Only the ***actual type*** [...] is
> used to determine whether to apply the resource, not the
> aforementioned assumed type.
>
> **Source:** https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#concept-link-type-sniffing

All this suggests to me, that it's *probably still a good idea* to always include the `type` attribute for `<link rel="icon">` - even if it's not strictly required by the spec.

Answer (score 2):

The whatwg.org site itself doesn't use the type attribute for their SVG logo, so I think it's safe to assume that it's not necessary.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-type

> The type attribute gives the MIME type of the linked resource. **It is purely advisory**. The value must be a valid MIME type string.
>
> For external resource links, the type attribute is used as a hint to user agents so that they can avoid fetching resources they do not support.